# How to select the first item in list by default with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i want select the first item in list by default.So when i open the view i want the item **Plafond sécurité sociale** under **Général** to be selected by default.

When i open the view it seems that my item is selected but it returns quickly closed and i'am using Jquery 3.3.1

```js
$(function () {
    $(".a.mdc-list-item:first").one("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
   
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <a class="mdc-list-item" style="width:100%;margin-right:3px;margin-left:3px;">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="row" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#général" style="cursor:pointer">
              <span class="user" style="font-weight:bold">Général</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="col-md-1 chevron-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#général" style="float:right;margin-right:0px">
              <i class="général_arrow material-icons float-right material-expand ripple" style="color: #0047FD !important;">
                         expand_more
                         </i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="général" class="collapse">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="PSS" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer;">
                   Plafond sécurité sociale
                   </a>
          <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="SMIC" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer;">
                   Smic
                   </a>
          <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="CSG" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer;">
                   CSG CRDS
                   </a>
          <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="AGM" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                   Abattement gérant majoritaire
                   </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give us a live example that reproduce the issue

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki didn't understand you i posted my code

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I made the snippet executable (by including jQuery)

Comment: @mecab1995 by "selected" you just mean to change the background colour? Or it should record the "selection" somewhere in a variable as well? P.S. I don't understand what your "click" event is for...it doesn't do anything useful (it won't even select any elements), and it has nothing to do with what you've requested in the question.

Comment: Since your list items are hard-coded, why not just add your selected class to the first? That's how Bootstrap does it.

Comment: See the `.active` class here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#list-group-linked

Comment: @isherwood so how i will change my code ?

Comment: @mecab1995 I think isherwood means by adding the "active" class to your first list item. `<a class="mdc-list-item active" tauxPlafonds="PSS"` but I don't know Bootstrap in enough detail to know if that's accurate

Comment: @ADyson i want just the item to be selected or clicked by default

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Anchors can't be "selected" or "checked". We assume, therefore, that you're asking about active state styling. Since you aren't using a Bootstrap list structure, the `active` class may not have an effect. I suggest that you consider refactoring to use a Bootstrap structure.

Comment: @mecab1995 yes I realise, I just meant maybe you need to record that status somewhere other than just in the HTML - sometimes that's necessary in an application

Comment: @isherwood yes active dosn't work with anchor element that why i tried to work with jquery so what can i do ? can i change the anchor elements with another bootstrap element and add the active class ? but the style stay the same ?

Comment: @mecab1995 ADyson is right. Your onClick function of yesterday is handling that only one list item is selected at a time. Just add your list-item-selected class to your first „a“ tag like ADyson just mentioned. Everything else should be handled by the code we provided yesterday

Comment: @KaiLeßmeister yes it is working but Général is not open by default i should open it to see the default item selected

Comment: it is working but i want when i click to another item the item selected by default disappear

Comment: @mecab1995 when using bootstrap with collapse bootstrap adds a „show“ class to the div collapsing when its not collapsed. I guess it was show but im not sure. Just try in your browser and look at the classes of your items when collapsed and not. Then add the class added of bootstrap when showing menually to your collapsing div where your first selected item is in.

Comment: @KaiLeßmeister it is working but i want when i click to another item the item selected by default disappear because he still selected for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With css only create class active

```
.active {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Add this class to your first  tag

```
  <a class="mdc-list-item active" tauxPlafonds="PSS" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer;">
               Plafond sécurité sociale
    </a>
```

To remove class use this function to add click event for all links except for the first

```
 $("a.mdc-list-item:not(:first)").on("click", function (event) {
    $("a.mdc-list-item:first").removeClass("active");
 });
```

Comment: it is working but i want when i click to another item the item selected by default disappear

Comment: i have the same problem the first item still selected despite i clicked to another item

Comment: I think you don’t need preventDefault()

Comment: i removed it but i have the same problem

Comment: Ok when you select a link other than first does class active removed

Comment: no the class active didn't removed if i select other than first or if i click to first also

Answer (score 2):

`<a>` is an element, not a class attribute. You do not want to prefix it with a dot `.`.

Did you try ?

```
$(function () {
    $("a.mdc-list-item:first").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).html());

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your point clearly,if you want to select the first element you can use this code at your function,

```
$(function () {
$(".mdc-list-item:first-child").css("background-color", "yellow");
        $(".mdc-list-item:first-child").on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

        });
    });
```

if suppose you dont ask this,tell me your need cleary